# How to recover XP with Ubuntu installed?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp

I installed Ubuntu in my laptop which had XP. For sometime it was fine, but suddenly the XP went to the blue screen of death and never recovered. It just keeps restarting if I select XP in the start up menu. Is there any chance of recovering it?

Answer (score 2):

if you run an XP recover from the XP install disk it will overwrite the Ubuntu bootloader (now a new problem) and then allow you to fix XP if it is fixable. After this I then use a "grub recover" disk which is debian based and moves GRUB back to the MBR

Comment: make sure you do a hard disk error check chkdsk before doing this, sometimes XP files are corrupt and prevent it from starting, with the installation cd go into the recovery console, if that doesnt fix it, try the solution by David it will surely fix it.